# Kendo UI Grid hide control in client template on dataBound

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid view and I'm using a client template which consists of an anchor tag and a label. What I need to do is to hide the anchor tag in the onDatabound event of the grid view.

Here is the grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GridView.DataSource)
    .Name("grdRole")
    .Columns(columns =>
             {
                 columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(110);
                 columns.Bound(p => p.Code);
                 columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                 columns.Bound(p => p.Id).ClientTemplate("<a id='lnkDisplay' href='' onclick='return linkOnClick()'> Display Data</a> <label id='lblShow'> gfhfhf</label> ").Title("Data");

             })  

    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
         .Events(x =>
                 {
                     x.Edit("onEdit");
                     x.Save("onSave");
                     x.DataBound("onDataBound");
                 })
      .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Create())
    .Sortable(x => x.Enabled(false))
    .Scrollable(x => x.Height("auto"))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
        })
            .Read(read => read.Action("OnGridRead", "Grid"))
                    .Create(create => create.Action("OnGridCreate", "Grid"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("OnGridUpdate", "Grid"))

    )
)
```

And here what I've tried to do..

```
 function onDataBound(e) {      
        var trs = this.wrapper.find('.k-grid-content tr');
        trs.each(function () {

           var id = this.childNodes[5].childNodes[0].hide();
        });
});
```

It gives me the following error..

> TypeError: this.childNodes[5].firstChild.hide is not a function

Comment: its because you call jquery method on DOM element, but it must be jquery object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a confusing way of selecting the anchor elements in your event. Why won't you simplify it (and keep it full jQuery instead of mix vanilla code)?

```
$(this.element).find('tr td a').hide()
```

The above selector will hide any anchor element in your grid, but in case of having another anchor elements, add a class in which elements you want to hide, e.g.:

```
.ClientTemplate("<a id='lnkDisplay' class='hide-me-at-data-bound' href='' onclick='return linkOnClick()'> Display Data</a>
```

Then just do:

```
$(this.element).find('.hide-me-at-data-bound').hide()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/uLOXo)**</kbd>

Besides, the error you're getting is because you can't call jQuery's `.hide()` on a non jQuery object. This - if your DOM navigation is ok - will probably work:

```
$(this.childNodes[5].childNodes[0]).hide();
```

<sup>PS: All your template anchors haves the same `id` which isn't a good practice. Try not to repeat an `id` in your html document.</sup>